# How to refer to the title of a section, as a bookmark in a separate md file, by a menu link?

Tags: html, markdown, hugo

I have a Hugo-driven structure as below

```
- config
    - _default
        - menus.yaml

- content
    - authors
        - admin
            - _index.md
    - home
        - A.md
```

According to this structure, `A` is section of my home page. Now, what I want is when one presses a menu entry `A_button`, it jumps at the start of Section `A` in my home page. So, let's say we have `A.md` as follows:

```
---
title: <div id="section-A">Section A</div>
subtitle: ''
---
Some text
```

But I don't know how I should refer to this bookmark in my `menus.yaml`. In particular, the following does not work.

```
main:
  - name: Home
    url: '/index.html'
    weight: 1
  - name: A_button
    url: 'index.html/#section-A'
    weight: 10
```

How can I achieve this bookmarking?